# Como apresentar somente valores negativos em C?

Tags: c, if, for

Eu tenho três variáveis :

```
int numero1,numero2,numero3;
```

Depois de ter declarado elas, eu estou perguntado ao usuário para preencher elas :

```
        printf("Digite o primeiro numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero1);
        printf("Digite o segundo numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d",&numero2);
        printf("Digite o terceiro numero inteiro: ");
        scanf ("%d",&numero3);
```

**E com base nisto, eu preciso verificar quais dos números digitados pelo usuário são negativos.**

Eu tenho um método que verifica se os números digitados são positivos :

```
void Positivo(int valor) {
        for(count = 1;count <= valor; count++) {
            if(count > 0) {
                printf("%d \n",count);
            }
        }
    }
```

E eu também tenho um que verifica se os números digitados são negativos :

```
void Negativo(int valor) {
    for(count = 0;count >= valor; count++) {
        if(count < 0) {
            printf("%d \n", count);
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que ao digitar os números, eles não aparecem nada, pois parece de que não é reconhecido pela função `scanf()` os números negativos.

Screenshot do programa :

[image]

Então, como posso resolver isto ? Fazendo com que ao usuário digitar os números negativos, possa ler da forma correta as variáveis, e mostrar somente os números negativos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só precisa de verificar, se o número é maior ou menor que `0`.

```
void negativo_print(int a);
void positivo_print(int a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int a, b, c;

    puts("Digite o primeiro digito:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    puts("Digite o segundo digito:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    puts("Digite o terceiro digito:");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    negativo_print(a);
    negativo_print(b);
    negativo_print(c);

    return 0;
}

void negativo_print(int a){
    if(a < 0){
        printf("Numero: %d\n", a);
    }
}
void positivo_print(int a){
    if(a > 0){
        printf("Numero: %d\n", a);
    }
}
```

Você pode também usar matrizes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n[2], i;
    size_t tmh = *(&n + 1) - n;

    puts("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n[0]);
    puts("\nDigite o segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n[1]);
    puts("\nDigite o terceiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n[2]);

    for(i=0; i<tmh+1; i++){
        if(negativo(n[i])){
            printf("numero: %i\n", n[i]);
        }
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No loop *for* verifica simplesmente se o número é negativo. Se for imprime na tela, caso não salta para a próxima iteração se houver.

E criar uma função que verifica se o número é positivo ou negativo, o zero é neutro:

```
int negativo(int a){
    if(a < 0) 
    {
        //negativo
        return 1;
    }
    // positvo
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acredito eu de que no caso, quem postou o problema, não quer usar arrays para resolver o problema, já que segundo o que próprio mostra no problema, pretende usar números inteiros.

Comment: Então, é exatamente o que o @Falion disse, eu preciso usar números inteiros e não arrays. Se possível, gostaria de saber como fazer a verificação com os números inteiros.

Comment: @Edilson Não fui eu que negativei, nem sequer tenho pontos suficientes para poder negativar. Obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: @Edilson Funcionou o código, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Mondial certo, problema vai ser se tiver que adicionar mais números.